# CSS translate(transform) -100% moves more than 100%

Tags: css

I'm building a slider that has items. Arrow clicks change the slider index which in turn moves the items.

At slider-index 0 things look fine:
[image]

With a few clicks, it starts getting weird.

[image]
At the end of the line, its completely out.

[image]

Container has slider plus two arrows. Slider has slider items. Each slider item has the image plus other items.

Here's my CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 25%;
}
.slider {
  margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
  --items-per-screen: 4;
  --slider-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slider-item{
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--slider-index) * -100%));
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;  
}
.handle{
  flex: 0 0 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Browser: Safari 14.1.2

Comment: It might be worth checking something like [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/demos) out instead of building it yourself :) if you can provide a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I might be able to help debugging

Answer (score 0):

Still couldn't get the 100% transform to work. I believe it is because the 100% will always be an unending number in pixels like 342.32324324243... etc.

I switched it to using set pixels and that works no problem.